# Best way to integrate an array of samples in python?

Tags: python, arrays, integration

I need to perform a definite integral in python (or, alternatively, in fortran), but instead of having a function I have an array of samples. I'm currently using the method given by scipy.integrate.trapz. However I'm wondering if there is an alternative method to perform such operation (for instance, the quadrature method would be a good one, but I'm afraid I can use functions but not arrays of samples). Any suggestion?

Comment: Sample input and expected output would be great.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only array of samples you can use  [numpy.trapz(y[,x])](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html) instead of scipy.integrate.trapz